# Use of unresolved identifier error in an extension file?

Tags: swift, swift3, nsattributedstring

I am making an extension for converting html to an attributed string, the code is

```
extension String {
var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
    guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return nil }
    do {
        return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return  nil
    }
}
var html2String: String {
    return htmlToAttributedString?.string ?? ""
}
```

I am getting the following 3 same errors

> Use of unresolved identifier 'NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'NSHTMLTextDocumentType'
>
> Use of unresolved identifier 'NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute'

i assume i have made a mistake with the syntax to cause 3 of the same error but i couldnt see what else the extension would need?

Thanks

Comment: Are you properly importing UIKit?

Comment: Import UIKit (iOS) or AppKit (macOS)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute`, `NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute`, `NSHTMLTextDocumentType` and
other keys and values for document attribute dictionaries
are defined in
the AppKit framework (macOS) or in the UIKit framework (iOS):

```
#if os(macOS)
    import AppKit
#elseif os(iOS)
    import UIKit
#endif
```